# Altorouter cant figure out how to route correctly PHP

Tags: php, routes, altorouter

if you haven't used this before the link is: http://altorouter.com/

I am making a small application but do not require a framework, only the routing part. So I've decided to try altorouter out as it seemed quite simple.

I want to map certain routes to do certain things. for example:

www.example.com/products/

this should show my products.php template and pull data from the database to populate the fields. I have got this working with the following:

```
$router->map( 'GET', '/products', function() {
    require('partials/connectdb.php'); //Require Database Connection
    $pageContent = getProductsContent($conn); //prepare all the page content from database
    require __DIR__ . '/products.php'; //require the template to use
});
```

The same for all of the other standard pages, my problem is when the route can change. For example:

www.example.com/shoes/

www.example.com/shorts/

www.example.com/shirts/

www.example.com/ties/

When a user goes to these routes I want to get the param 'shoes' and then while still using the products.php template, do the logic for only shoes.

So looking at the docs it says you can do:

www.example.com/[*] //which means anything.

However after adding this into my listed routes, it voids anything else the user trys to visit. So if they visit:

www.example.com/products // Like it worked before

It actually does the logic inside:

www.example.com/[*]

Does anyone know altorouter and can help me out please? I will paste my full page code below:

```
// Site Router
$router->map( 'GET', '/', function() {
    require('partials/connectdb.php'); //Require Database Connection
    $pageContent = getHomeContent($conn);
    require __DIR__ . '/home.php';
});


$router->map( 'GET', '/products', function() {
    require('partials/connectdb.php'); //Require Database Connection
    $pageContent = getProductsContent($conn);
    require __DIR__ . '/products.php';
});


$router->map( 'GET', '/[*]', function($id) {
    require('partials/connectdb.php'); //Require Database Connection


    $test = 'this was a test';
    $pageContent = getProductsContent($conn);
    require __DIR__ . '/products.php';
});

// match current request url
$match = $router->match();

// call closure or throw 404 status
if( $match && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {
    call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] );
} else {
    // no route was matched
    header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url should be

`www.example.com/products/`

`www.example.com/products/shoes`

`www.example.com/products/shirts`

Then you can do this:

```
$router->map( 'GET', '/products/:type', function($type) {
   require('partials/connectdb.php'); //Require Database Connection

   if(!isset($type)){
     $pageContent = getProductsContent($conn); //prepare all the page content from database
     require __DIR__ . '/products.php'; //require the template to use

    if($type == 'shoes'){
      //do this
      echo 'shoes';
    }
    if($type == 'shirts'){
      //do that
      echo 'shirts';
    }
});
```

Comment: no error, just blank page, if you look on altorouter website :type isnt a thing that can be used i think

Comment: So how would i register :Type using addMatchTypes(). I dont understsand that part

Comment: I am looking into Altorouter. Will tell you once I done

Comment: I have managed to get it working now, im just using /products/[*] then manually getting the last string after the last /